# Extract Content From HTML with PHP

Tags: php, html, regex

Here is my HTML file:

```
<html>
  <head>    
    <link href='http://wendyandgabe.blogspot.com/favicon.ico' rel='icon' type='image/x-icon'/>
    <link href='http://wendyandgabe.blogspot.com/' rel='canonical'/>
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="O&#39; Happy Day! - Atom" href="http://wendyandgabe.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default" />
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="O&#39; Happy Day! - RSS" href="http://wendyandgabe.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss" />
    <link rel="service.post" type="application/atom+xml" title="O&#39; Happy Day! - Atom" href="http://www.blogger.com/feeds/5390468261501503598/posts/default" />
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to extract the url of href where `type="application/rss+xml"` from the above html file. How is it possible? Can anybody show some example code?

Comment: take a look at DomDocument & DomXPath ...

Comment: You can use PHP DOM for this http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Answer (score 2):

You can use

DomDocument http://php.net/manual/de/class.domdocument.php and

and

DomXPath http://de3.php.net/manual/de/class.domxpath.php

```
$html = <<<EOF
<html>
  <head>    
    <link href='http://wendyandgabe.blogspot.com/favicon.ico' rel='icon' type='image/x-icon'/>
    <link href='http://wendyandgabe.blogspot.com/' rel='canonical'/>
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="O&#39; Happy Day! - Atom" href="http://wendyandgabe.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default" />
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="O&#39; Happy Day! - RSS" href="http://wendyandgabe.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss" />
    <link rel="service.post" type="application/atom+xml" title="O&#39; Happy Day! - Atom" href="http://www.blogger.com/feeds/5390468261501503598/posts/default" />
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
EOF;

$xml = new DomDocument;
$xml->loadHTML($html);

//create a xpath instance
$xpath = new DomXpath($xml);

//query for <link type="application/rss+xml"> and use the first found item
$link = $xpath->query('//link[@type="application/rss+xml"]')->item(0);


var_dump($link->getAttribute('href'));
```

http://3v4l.org/PkH8n

Comment: working perfectly,but when i load html from external it shows errors,
$html = file_get_contents("http://wendyandgabe.blogspot.com");

Comment: here is my edited code, but this is not working.

<?php
$html = file_get_contents("http://wendyandgabe.blogspot.com");

$xml = new DomDocument;
$xml->loadXML($html);

$xpath = new DomXpath($xml);

$link = $xpath->query('//link[@type="application/rss+xml"]')->item(0);


echo $link->getAttribute('href');
?>

Comment: try `->loadHTML()` instead of `->loadXML()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this PHP class DOMDocument

http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Answer (score 0):

Using [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), here's how:

```
// includes Simple HTML DOM Parser
include "simple_html_dom.php";

$text = '<html>
  <head>    
    <link href="http://wendyandgabe.blogspot.com/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <link href="http://wendyandgabe.blogspot.com/" rel="canonical"/>
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="O&#39; Happy Day! - Atom" href="http://wendyandgabe.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default" />
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="O&#39; Happy Day! - RSS" href="http://wendyandgabe.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss" />
    <link rel="service.post" type="application/atom+xml" title="O&#39; Happy Day! - Atom" href="http://www.blogger.com/feeds/5390468261501503598/posts/default" />
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>';


//Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a string
$html->load($text);


// Find the link with the appropriate selectors
$link = $html->find('link[type=application/rss+xml]', 0);


// Find succeeded
if ($link) {
    $href = $link->href;
    echo $href;
}
else
    echo "Find function failed !";


// Clear DOM object (needed essentially when using many)
$html->clear(); 
unset($html);

OUTPUT 
======
http://wendyandgabe.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss
```

[DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/bfq-ggu)